# How do I sample from a custom distribution?

Tags: r

I have the pdf of a distribution. This distribution is not a standard distribution and no functions exist in R to sample from it.  How to I sample from this pdf using R?

Comment: Is the pdf defined as a mere function? Does the answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/generating-random-samples-from-a-custom-distribution) help? (Otherwise, give us some more info, perhaps how the PDF is defined.)

Comment: The PDF is f(X)=exp(-a*x-Igamma(b,c*x^-d, lower=FALSE))*(a+(((c^b)*d)/x^(1+d*b))*exp(-c*x^-d)). Where lgamma is the upper incomplete gamma function?

Comment: If `a` through `d` are simple parameters, could you use `x <- runif(n)` and plug in all the rest to your function? (Is your `x` input continuous on `[0,1]`?)

Comment: This is the R code I used. I got a sample but I am not sure if it is right.  
 x <- runif(100)
 f <- function(x, u) 1-exp(-a*x-Igamma(b,c*x^-d, lower=FALSE)) - u
z <- c()

 my.uniroot <- function(x) uniroot(f, c(0,10000000000), tol = 0.0001, u = x)$root
 system.time({
   r <- vapply(x, my.uniroot, numeric(1))
 })

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a statistics question, as it requires sampling, but in general, you can take this approach to the problem:

1. Find a distribution `f`, whose pdf, when multiplied by any given constant `k`, is always greater than the pdf of the distribution in question, `g`.
2. For each sample, do the following steps:
3. Sample a random number `x` from the distribution `f`.
4. Calculate `C = f(x)*k/g(x)`. This should be equal to or less than 1.
5. Draw a random number `u` from a uniform distribution U(0,1).  If `C < u`, then go back to step 3.  Otherwise keep `x` as the number and continue sampling if desired.

This process is known as rejection sampling, and is often used in random number generators that are not uniform.

The normal distribution and the uniform distribution are some of the more common distributions to sample from, but you can do other ones.  Generally you want the shapes of `k*f(x)` and `g(x)` to be very close, so you don't have to reject a lot of samples.

Here's an example implementation:

```
#n is sample size
#g is pdf you want to sample from
#rf is sampling function for f
#df is density function for f
#k is multiplicative constant
#... is any necessary parameters for f
function.sample <- function(n,g,rf,df,k,...){
    results = numeric(n)
    counter = 0
    while(counter < n){
        x = rf(1,...)
        x.pdf = df(x,...)
        if (runif(0,1) >= x.pdf * k/g(x)){
            results[counter+1] = x
            counter = counter + 1
        }
    }
}
```

There are other methods to do random sampling, but this is usually the easiest, and it works well for most functions (unless their PDF is hard to calculate but their CDF isn't).