# Generating random values via linearly decreasing function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to randomly select values between 2 points so that the most likely ones are selected closer to the left boundary and decrease linearly over the range.

Like this but so that values closer to the min and more likely than ones closer to the max

```
runif(1, min=11700, max=126000)
```

Comment: These posts may help, but you will need to formalize your distribution more first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325459/generate-random-number-from-custom-distribution, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/generating-random-samples-from-a-custom-distribution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627487/how-do-i-sample-from-a-custom-distribution

Comment: You need to create a custom random number generator because `runif` generates random sample from a uniform distribution.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at those already, but I thought given that I want it to decrease linearly over the range it would be more straight forward

Comment: decrease linearly over the range. How to you visualize the function?

Comment: Like a right-angled triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the beta distribution and then scale up the values to get a 'lefty' distribution

```
fun <- function(n) {
  11700 + (126000 - 11700) * rbeta(n, 1, 3) # a < b will tilt left 
}

hist(fun(1000))
```

Comment: its perfect with a=1 and b=2